# Easymock createMock vs @Mock

Tags: unit-testing, junit, easymock

I'm using Easymock with junit for writing my unit tests. I have seen different tests following different methods to create mock objects. 
Is there any difference between Easymock.createMock() and @Mock annotation ?

```
Obj obj = EasyMock.createMock(Obj.class);
```

and

```
@Mock
private Obj obj;
```

Is there any difference between the two ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The annotated way of creating the mock is only available since EasyMock 3.2. With the `@Mock` annotation the mock is injected, otherwise it's created by you.

From a functional viewpoint, they are the same, it's just the way you set things up/configure it that is different.

I noticed you allready asked some questions about EasyMock, be sure to check the [userguide](http://easymock.org/user-guide.html), it's an easy to read guide with a lot of good examples!

Comment: Using `@Mock` can also avoid compiler warnings when the type you need to mock is generic.