# EasyMock @Mock is not working same as createMock for abstract classes

Tags: java, unit-testing, annotations, mocking, easymock

As per the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30527972/easymock-createmock-vs-mock), @Mock annotation and createMock are same from functionality view. But, I am facing a strange issue while using these. Little background here.

I have to test ClassUnderTest which calls method from Abstractclass. When I should call from the unit test to ClassUnderTest, I expect the Abstractclass method to be called.

`

```
    public abstract AbstractClass {

        public void addValue(int a, int b) {
        // Invoking another method which is abstract.
        };
    }


    public class ClassUnderTest {

        public Abstractclass obj;
        public ClassUnderTest(Abstractclass obj) {
        // Parameterized constructor.
        }
        public MethodToTest(){ 
             object.addValue(1, 2); // Calls the method.
        }
    }

@RunWith(EasyMockRunner.class)
public class TestFile {
    @Mock
    private AbstractClass concrete;
    @Test
    public void testMethod() {
    concrete = EasyMock.createMock(AbstractClass.class);

    concrete.addValue(1,2);
    EasyMock.expectLastCall().once();
    EasyMock.replay();
    new ClassUnderTest().methodToTest();
    EasyMock.verify() // The code under scan.
    }  
}
```

`
I am facing these issues:

1. When I am using @Mock annotation, EasyMock verify throws an error saying Abstractclass.addValue() expectation is not fulfilled.
2. But, when I remove @Mock annotation, it works fine and no error is there.
3. For Non abstract classes, @Mock is working fine for me.

Could anybody please explain this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Your real code must be different from this one. Both should behave exactly the same. Otherwise it is a bug. I tried your code (applying a lot of fixes. You should post correctly running examples next time). It works perfectly. Here is it

```
abstract class AbstractClass {

  public abstract void foo();

  public void addValue(int a, int b) {
    foo();
  }
}

class ClassUnderTest {

  private AbstractClass obj;

  public ClassUnderTest(AbstractClass obj) {
    this.obj = obj;
  }

  public void methodToTest(){
    obj.addValue(1, 2); // Calls the method.
  }
}

@RunWith(EasyMockRunner.class)
public class TestFile {
  @Mock
  private AbstractClass concrete;

  @Test
  public void testMethod() {
//    concrete = EasyMock.createMock(AbstractClass.class);

    concrete.addValue(1,2);
    EasyMock.replay();
    new ClassUnderTest(concrete).methodToTest();
    EasyMock.verify(); // The code under scan.
  }
}
```

To be super clear. These 4 mean **exactly** the same thing:

```
// 1. Calling once the void method
concrete.addValue(1,2);
// 2. Calling once the void method and then using expectLastCall()
concrete.addValue(1,2);
expectLastCall();
// 3. Calling once the void method and then expect once
concrete.addValue(1,2);
expectLastCall().once();
// 4. Calling once the void method and then expect one time
concrete.addValue(1,2);
expectLastCall().time(1);
```

Comment: What if I have to check that concrete.addValue(1,2) is called exactly once and not more than that? As this a void method, I can't use expect and then return, so I used ExpectLastCall once for that.

Comment: Just recording by calling the void method once is a synonym. I have updated my answer to make it super clear.